# how can i set initial value for usestate from redux state using selector in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, use-state

when I try to set initial value from redux state, there is nothing on text component but i can see the value on console

```
   const Profile = props => {

   const userName = useSelector(userSelector);
   const [name, setName] = useState(userName);
   
   console.log(userName);
   
       return (
           <Text>{name}</Text>

       );
};
```

Comment: You don't need to use `useState` until you need it to change locally because using selector redux, will auto update when it changes.

Comment: Can you close this question...and accept the answer if you got it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It won't work this way, as redux is getting its value after the initial render so you need to update your state only after the redux value is updated

> If your redux store is a string you can directly use userName in place of name.

> Use an useEffect hook and add userName to its dependency array.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  setName(userName);
}, [userName])
```

Add this inside your react component and it will work!!

Comment: What is the source of this information? I can't find any reference to this. I also never had a problem when using selector as initial data in useState.